¿Como volver a poder utilizar el check?
Después de marcar todas las casillas en el espacio de selección, si las desmarco todas, no puedo volver a usar la directiva.
Asi que si alguien me podriar ayudar se agradeceria. Saludos
  @Directive({
      selector: '[nextCheckbox]'
    })
    export class NextCheckboxDirective {
      constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }
      @HostListener('keydown.space', ['$event'])
      onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ion-checkbox'));
        const currentIndex = checkboxes.findIndex((checkbox) => checkbox === this.element.nativeElement);
        if(checkboxes[currentIndex].checked === false){
          checkboxes[currentIndex].click();
        }
        if(currentIndex !== -1 && currentIndex < checkboxes.length - 1){
          const nextCheckbox = checkboxes[currentIndex + 1];
          const inputCheck = nextCheckbox.shadowRoot.querySelector('input');
          if(inputCheck){
            if (!inputCheck.checked) {
              inputCheck.checked = true;
              inputCheck.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
              inputCheck.focus();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

